# ajax method post send to mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I pass the variable javascript method by ajax post method to the php file in this way:

```
$(".btn_ranking").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
        var time = localStorage.getItem('timer_end');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/file.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                name: name,
                time: time
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Request Payload in my Browser returns: `name=Adrian&time=00%3A01%3A59`. What should I write in the file `file.php` to send variables using sql query to my mysql database?

Comment: You should start with `<?php` ...

Comment: please show your `file.php` to see what you've got so far!

Comment: @Rainmx93 — That won't work. Since the code claims to be sending JSON (which is a lie), `$_POST` won't be populated.

Comment: Your question is *far* too broad. You're essentially asking for an introductory PHP and MySQL tutorial. There are plenty out there already, try starting with one of those and only asking here when you have a more specific question.

Answer (score -1):

You can make good use of php explode() method here:

`$string = name=Adrian&time=00%3A01%3A59
$parameters = explode("&", name=Adrian&time=00%3A01%3A59)`

This will give you an array `$parameters`:

(`$parameters[0] == name=Adrian`,
`$parameters[1] == time=00%3A01%3A59`)

Now you can get the name and time from `$parameters`:

`$name = explode("=", $parameters[0])[1];
$time = explode("=", $parameters[1])[1];`

Comment: Your PHP it littered with syntax errors, does a massive amount of wheel reinvention, fails to explain how to get the data from the HTTP request, and fails to explain anything about how to insert the data into MySQL.

Comment: I understood from the question that OP is getting the string `name=Adrian&time=00%3A01%3A59` and wants to get the name and time values out of it, which my code does. I could've explained how to insert them into a database, but that's so basic I assumed he knew it already (and if he didn't, he could easily look it up).

Comment: Okay, but `name` and `time` can be different. the user enters them every time.

Comment: Yes, that's why you get the name and time by splitting up the string. `$name` and `$time` from my example will always correspond to the name and time entered.